# Why would the "View Dependencies" not show foreign keys between tables on 2 databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssms, data-modeling

I have something minor, yet very odd happening in SQL Server Management Studio 2005. I have 2 database catalogs which are essentially identical. There is a Market table with a foreign key to other several other tables for example the "Project" table has a MarketID column with an FK reference from dbo.Market. in both db catalogs the MarketID is not null, the datatype is the same (int - obviously) and in both db catalogs there is a foreign key created between the two tables (from dbo.Market to dbo.Project).

on the PRD catalog if I right click the Market table and choose "View Dependencies" from the context menu I will see the tables where MarketId is a foreign key on other tables (e.g. dbo.Project will appear under "Objects that depend upon Market"). If I do the same thing on the other db catalog (TST) it does not show that there are any foreign keys. PRD and TST catalogs are hosted on the same db server, so it's not a case of one catalog has a different version or SP of SS Management Studio or something... what gives?

What is even more strange is if I create a database diagram on both catalogs, the foreign keys look the same for all the tables compared, but the behaviour of the "View Dependencies" is different. If I look at the "Indexes" and "Statistics" for the tables on each catalog they are essentially identical too... I am baffled.

Can anyone suggest what things would impact the visibility of foreign key relationships in the tree that is shown when you choose the "View Dependencies"

Initially we thought wtf who removed the foreign keys, but when we look at a data diagram or the foreign keys folder they are there...

Comment: what does `select * from sys.foreign_keys where referenced_object_id = object_id('dbo.Market')` return for both?

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Profiler this is the script SSMS uses. I guess it's just a question of running it your end to see what's different between the two databases.

```
USE TST

CREATE TABLE #tempdep (objid int NOT NULL, objtype smallint NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #tempdep 

SELECT
tbl.object_id AS [ID],
3
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
WHERE
(tbl.name=N'Market' and SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)=N'dbo');

declare @find_referencing_objects int
set @find_referencing_objects = 1
-- parameters:
-- 1. create table #tempdep (objid int NOT NULL, objtype smallint NOT NULL)
--    contains source objects
-- 2. @find_referencing_objects defines ordering
--    1 order for drop
--    0 order for script

declare @must_set_nocount_off bit
set @must_set_nocount_off = 0

IF @@OPTIONS & 512 = 0 
   set @must_set_nocount_off = 1
set nocount on

declare @u int
declare @udf int
declare @v int
declare @sp int
declare @def int
declare @rule int
declare @tr int
declare @uda int
declare @uddt int
declare @xml int
declare @udt int
declare @assm int
declare @part_sch int
declare @part_func int
declare @synonym int

set @u = 3
set @udf = 0
set @v = 2
set @sp = 4
set @def = 6
set @rule = 7
set @tr = 8
set @uda = 11
set @synonym = 12
--above 100 -> not in sys.objects
set @uddt = 101
set @xml = 102
set @udt = 103
set @assm = 1000
set @part_sch = 201
set @part_func = 202


/*
 * Create #t1 as temp object holding areas.  Columns are:
 *  object_id     - temp object id
 *  object_type    - temp object type
 *  relative_id      - parent or child object id
 *  relative_type  - parent or child object type
 *  rank  - NULL means dependencies not yet evaluated, else nonNULL.
 *   soft_link - this row should not be used to compute ordering among objects
 *   object_name - name of the temp object
 *   object_schema - name the temp object's schema (if any)
 *   relative_name - name of the relative object
 *   relative_schema - name of the relative object's schema (if any)
 *   degree - the number of relatives that the object has, will be used for computing the rank
 *   object_key - surrogate key that combines object_id and object_type
 *   relative_key - surrogate key that combines relative_id and relative_type
 */
create table #t1(
   object_id         int         NULL,
   object_type       smallint    NULL,
   relative_id       int         NULL,
   relative_type        smallint    NULL,
   rank        smallint    NULL,
   soft_link      bit      NULL,
   object_name       sysname     NULL,
   object_schema        sysname     NULL,
   relative_name     sysname     NULL,
   relative_schema      sysname     NULL,
   degree            int NULL,
   object_key bigint NULL,
   relative_key bigint NULL
)

create unique clustered index i1 on #t1(object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type) with IGNORE_DUP_KEY

declare @iter_no int
set @iter_no = 1

declare @rows int
set @rows = 1

declare @rowcount_ck int
set @rowcount_ck = 0

insert #t1 (relative_id, relative_type, rank) 
   select l.objid, l.objtype, @iter_no from #tempdep l

while @rows > 0
begin
   set @rows = 0
   if( 1 = @find_referencing_objects )
   begin
      --tables that reference uddts or udts (parameters that reference types are in sql_dependencies )
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, c.object_id, @u, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.columns as c on  c.user_type_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.tables as tbl on tbl.object_id = c.object_id -- eliminate views
         where @iter_no = t.rank and (t.relative_type=@uddt OR t.relative_type=@udt)
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --tables that reference defaults ( only default objects )
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, clmns.object_id, @u, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.columns as clmns on clmns.default_object_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.objects as o on o.object_id = t.relative_id and 0 = isnull(o.parent_object_id, 0)
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @def
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --types that reference defaults ( only default objects )
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, tp.user_type_id, @uddt, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.types as tp on tp.default_object_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.objects as o on o.object_id = t.relative_id and 0 = isnull(o.parent_object_id, 0)
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @def
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --tables that reference rules
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, clmns.object_id, @u, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.columns as clmns on clmns.rule_object_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @rule
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --types that reference rules
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, tp.user_type_id, @uddt, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.types as tp on tp.rule_object_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @rule
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --tables that reference XmlSchemaCollections
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, c.object_id, @u, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.columns as c on c.xml_collection_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.tables as tbl on tbl.object_id = c.object_id -- eliminate views
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @xml
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --procedures that reference XmlSchemaCollections
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, c.object_id, case when o.type in ( 'P', 'RF', 'PC' ) then @sp else @udf end, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.parameters as c on c.xml_collection_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.objects as o on o.object_id = c.object_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @xml
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --udf, sp, uda, trigger all that reference assembly
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, am.object_id, (case o.type when 'AF' then @uda when 'PC' then @sp when 'FS' then @udf when 'FT' then @udf when 'TA' then @tr else @udf end), @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.assembly_modules as am on am.assembly_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.objects as o on am.object_id = o.object_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @assm
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      -- CLR udf, sp, uda that reference udt
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select distinct t.relative_id, 
               t.relative_type, 
               am.object_id, 
               (case o.type 
                  when 'AF' then @uda 
                  when 'PC' then @sp 
                  when 'FS' then @udf 
                  when 'FT' then @udf 
                  when 'TA' then @tr 
                  else @udf end), 
               @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.parameters as sp on sp.user_type_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.assembly_modules as am on sp.object_id = am.object_id  
         join sys.objects as o on sp.object_id = o.object_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @udt
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --udt that reference assembly
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, at.user_type_id, @udt, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.assembly_types as at on at.assembly_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @assm
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --assembly that reference assembly
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, ar.assembly_id, @assm, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.assembly_references as ar on ar.referenced_assembly_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @assm
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --table references table
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, fk.parent_object_id, @u, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.foreign_keys as fk on fk.referenced_object_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @u
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --table,view references partition scheme
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)      
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, idx.object_id, case o.type when 'V' then @v else @u end, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.indexes as idx on idx.data_space_id = t.relative_id 
         join sys.objects as o on o.object_id = idx.object_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @part_sch
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --partition scheme references partition function
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)      
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, ps.data_space_id, @part_sch, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.partition_schemes as ps on ps.function_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @part_func
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --non-schema-bound parameter references type
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, p.object_id, 
               case when obj.type in ( 'P', 'PC' ) then @sp else @udf
               end, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.parameters as p on 
             p.user_type_id = t.relative_id and  t.relative_type in (@uddt, @udt)
         join sys.objects as obj on obj.object_id = p.object_id and obj.type in ( 'P',  'PC', 'TF', 'FN', 'IF', 'FS', 'FT')
         and ISNULL(objectproperty(obj.object_id, 'isschemabound'), 0) = 0
         where @iter_no = t.rank
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --view, procedure references table, view, procedure
      --procedure references type
      --table(check) references procedure
      --trigger references table, procedure
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, case when 'C' = obj.type then obj.parent_object_id else dp.object_id end, 
               case when obj.type  in ('U', 'C') then @u when 'V' = obj.type then @v when 'TR' = obj.type then @tr 
               when obj.type in ( 'P', 'RF', 'PC' ) then @sp 
               when obj.type in ( 'TF', 'FN', 'IF', 'FS', 'FT' ) then @udf
               end, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.sql_dependencies as dp on 
            -- reference table, view procedure
            ( class < 2 and dp.referenced_major_id = t.relative_id and t.relative_type in ( @u, @v, @sp, @udf) )
            --reference type
             or ( 2 = class  and dp.referenced_major_id = t.relative_id and  t.relative_type in (@uddt, @udt))
            --reference xml namespace ( not supported by server right now )
            --or ( 3 = class  and dp.referenced_major_id = t.relative_id and @xml = t.relative_type )
         join sys.objects as obj on obj.object_id = dp.object_id and obj.type in ( 'U', 'V', 'P', 'RF', 'PC', 'TR', 'TF', 'FN', 'IF', 'FS', 'FT', 'C')
         where @iter_no = t.rank
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

   end -- 1 = @find_referencing_objects
   else
   begin -- find referenced objects
      --check references table
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, dp.object_id, 77 /*place holder for check*/, @iter_no
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.sql_dependencies as dp on 
            -- reference table
            class < 2 and dp.referenced_major_id = t.relative_id and t.relative_type = @u
         join sys.objects as obj on obj.object_id = dp.object_id and obj.type  = 'C'
         where @iter_no = t.rank
      set @rowcount_ck = @@rowcount

      --non-schema-bound parameter references type
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select distinct 
            t.relative_id,  -- object_id
            t.relative_type,    -- object_type
            p.user_type_id, -- relative_id
            case p.system_type_id when 240 then @udt else @uddt end,
            @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.parameters as p on
             p.object_id = t.relative_id and p.user_type_id > 256 and t.relative_type in ( @sp, @udf )
             and ISNULL(objectproperty(p.object_id, 'isschemabound'), 0) = 0
         where @iter_no = t.rank
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --view, procedure referenced by table, view, procedure
      --type referenced by procedure
      --check referenced by table
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select distinct 
            case when 77 = t.relative_type then obj2.parent_object_id else t.relative_id end,   -- object_id
            case when 77 = t.relative_type then @u else relative_type end,                -- object_type
            dp.referenced_major_id,                                              -- relative_id
            case                                                           -- relative_type
               when dp.class < 2 then 
                  case when 'U' = obj.type then @u 
                  when 'V' = obj.type then @v 
                  when 'TR' = obj.type then @tr 
                  when 'AF' = obj.type then @uda 
                  when obj.type in ( 'P', 'RF', 'PC' ) then @sp 
                  when obj.type in ( 'TF', 'FN', 'IF', 'FS', 'FT' ) then @udf
                  when exists (select * from sys.synonyms syn where syn.object_id = dp.referenced_major_id ) then @synonym
                  end
               when dp.class = 2 then (case 
                                    when exists (select * from sys.assembly_types sat where sat.user_type_id = dp.referenced_major_id) then @udt 
                                    else @uddt 
                                 end) 
            end, 
            @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.sql_dependencies as dp on 
            -- reference table, view procedure
            ( class < 2 and dp.object_id = t.relative_id and t.relative_type in ( @u, @v, @sp, @udf, @tr, @uda, 77) )
            --reference type
             or ( 2 = class  and dp.object_id = t.relative_id ) -- t.relative_type?
            --reference xml namespace ( not supported by server right now )
            --or ( 3 = class  and dp.referenced_major_id = t.relative_id and @xml = t.relative_type )
         left join sys.objects as obj on obj.object_id = dp.referenced_major_id and dp.class < 2 and obj.type in ( 'U', 'V', 'P', 'RF', 'PC', 'TF', 'FN', 'IF', 'FS', 'FT', 'TR', 'AF')
         left join sys.objects as obj2 on obj2.object_id = t.relative_id and 77 = t.relative_type
         where @iter_no = t.rank
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      if @rowcount_ck > 0 
      begin
         delete from #t1 where relative_type = 77
      end

      --table or view referenced by trigger
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, tr.parent_id, case o.type when 'V' then @v else @u end, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.triggers as tr on tr.object_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.objects as o on o.object_id = tr.parent_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @tr
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --table referenced by table
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, fk.referenced_object_id, @u, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.foreign_keys as fk on fk.parent_object_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @u
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --assembly referenced by assembly
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, ar.referenced_assembly_id, @assm, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.assembly_references as ar on ar.assembly_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @assm
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --assembly referenced by udt
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, at.assembly_id, @assm, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.assembly_types as at on at.user_type_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @udt
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      -- assembly referenced by udf, sp, uda, trigger
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, am.assembly_id, @assm, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.assembly_modules as am on am.object_id = t.relative_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type in ( @udf, @sp, @uda, @tr)
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      -- udt referenced by CLR udf, sp, uda
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select distinct 
               t.relative_id, 
               t.relative_type, 
               at.user_type_id, 
               @udt, 
               @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.parameters as sp on sp.object_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.assembly_modules as am on am.object_id = sp.object_id
         join sys.assembly_types as at on sp.user_type_id = at.user_type_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type in (@udf, @sp, @uda)
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

      --clr types referenced by tables ( types referenced by parameters are in sql_dependencies )
      insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
         select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, c.user_type_id, @udt, @iter_no + 1
         from #t1 as t
         join sys.columns as c on  c.object_id = t.relative_id
         join sys.assembly_types as tp on tp.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
         where @iter_no = t.rank and t.relative_type = @u
      set @rows = @rows + @@rowcount

   end
   set @iter_no = @iter_no + 1
end --main loop

--objects that don't need to be in the loop because they don't reference anybody
if( 0 = @find_referencing_objects )
begin
   --alias types referenced by tables ( types referenced by parameters are in sql_dependencies )
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, c.user_type_id, @uddt, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.columns as c on  c.object_id = t.relative_id
      join sys.types as tp on tp.user_type_id = c.user_type_id and tp.is_user_defined = 1
      where t.relative_type = @u and tp.is_assembly_type = 0

   if @@rowcount > 0 
   begin
      set @iter_no = @iter_no + 1
   end

   --defaults referenced by types
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, tp.default_object_id, @def, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.types as tp on tp.user_type_id = t.relative_id and tp.default_object_id > 0
      join sys.objects as o on o.object_id = tp.default_object_id and 0 = isnull(o.parent_object_id, 0)
      where t.relative_type = @uddt

   --defaults referenced by tables( only default objects )
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, clmns.default_object_id, @def, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.columns as clmns on clmns.object_id = t.relative_id
      join sys.objects as o on o.object_id = clmns.default_object_id and 0 = isnull(o.parent_object_id, 0)
      where t.relative_type = @u

   --rules referenced by types
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, tp.rule_object_id, @rule, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.types as tp on tp.user_type_id = t.relative_id and tp.rule_object_id > 0
      where t.relative_type = @uddt

   --rules referenced by tables
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, clmns.rule_object_id, @rule, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.columns as clmns on clmns.object_id = t.relative_id and clmns.rule_object_id > 0
      where t.relative_type = @u

   --XmlSchemaCollections referenced by table
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, c.xml_collection_id, @xml, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.columns as c on c.object_id = t.relative_id and c.xml_collection_id > 0
      where t.relative_type = @u

   --XmlSchemaCollections referenced by procedures
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, c.xml_collection_id, @xml, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.parameters as c on c.object_id = t.relative_id and c.xml_collection_id > 0
      where t.relative_type in ( @sp, @udf)

   --partition scheme referenced by table,view
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)      
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, ps.data_space_id, @part_sch, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.indexes as idx on idx.object_id = t.relative_id 
      join sys.partition_schemes as ps on ps.data_space_id = idx.data_space_id
      where t.relative_type in (@u, @v)

   --partition function referenced by partition scheme
   insert #t1 (object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, rank)      
      select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, ps.function_id, @part_func, @iter_no + 1
      from #t1 as t
      join sys.partition_schemes as ps on ps.data_space_id = t.relative_id
      where t.relative_type = @part_sch

end

--cleanup circular references
delete #t1 where object_id = relative_id and object_type=relative_type

--allow circular dependencies by cuting one of the branches
--mark as soft links dependencies between tables
-- at script time we will need to take care to script fks and checks separately
update #t1 set soft_link = 1 where ( object_type = @u and relative_type = @u )

--add independent objects first in the list
insert #t1 ( object_id, object_type, rank) 
   select t.relative_id, t.relative_type, 1 from #t1 t where t.relative_id not in ( select t2.object_id from #t1 t2 where not t2.object_id is null )

--delete initial objects
delete #t1 where object_id is null

-- compute the surrogate keys to make sorting easier
update #t1 set object_key = object_id + convert(bigint, 0xfFFFFFFF) * object_type
update #t1 set relative_key = relative_id + convert(bigint, 0xfFFFFFFF) * relative_type

create index index_key on #t1 (object_key, relative_key)

update #t1 set rank = 0
-- computing the degree of the nodes
update #t1 set degree = (
      select count(*) 
      from #t1 t_alias 
      where t_alias.object_key = #t1.object_key and 
            t_alias.relative_id is not null and 
            t_alias.soft_link is null)

-- perform topological sorting 
set @iter_no=1
while 1=1
begin 
   update #t1 set rank=@iter_no where degree=0
   -- end the loop if no more rows left to process
   if (@@rowcount=0) break
   update #t1 set degree=NULL where rank = @iter_no

   update #t1 set degree = (
      select count(*) 
         from #t1 t_alias 
         where t_alias.object_key = #t1.object_key and 
            t_alias.relative_key is not null and 
            t_alias.relative_key in (select t_alias2.object_key from #t1 t_alias2 where t_alias2.rank=0 and t_alias2.soft_link is null) and
            t_alias.rank=0 and t_alias.soft_link is null)
      where degree is not null

   set @iter_no=@iter_no+1
end

--add name schema
update #t1 set object_name = o.name, object_schema = schema_name(o.schema_id)
from sys.objects AS o 
where o.object_id = #t1.object_id and object_type in ( @u, @udf, @v, @sp, @def, @rule, @uda)

update #t1 set relative_type = case op.type when 'V' then @v else @u end, object_name = o.name, object_schema = schema_name(o.schema_id), relative_name = op.name, relative_schema = schema_name(op.schema_id)
from sys.objects AS o 
join sys.objects AS op on op.object_id = o.parent_object_id
where o.object_id = #t1.object_id and object_type = @tr

update #t1 set object_name = t.name, object_schema = schema_name(t.schema_id)
from sys.types AS t
where t.user_type_id = #t1.object_id and object_type in ( @uddt, @udt )

update #t1 set object_name = x.name, object_schema = schema_name(x.schema_id)
from sys.xml_schema_collections AS x
where x.xml_collection_id = #t1.object_id and object_type = @xml

update #t1 set object_name = p.name, object_schema = null
from sys.partition_schemes AS p
where p.data_space_id = #t1.object_id and object_type = @part_sch


update #t1 set object_name = p.name, object_schema = null
from sys.partition_functions AS p
where p.function_id = #t1.object_id and object_type = @part_func

update #t1 set object_name = a.name, object_schema = null
from sys.assemblies AS a
where a.assembly_id = #t1.object_id and object_type = @assm

update #t1 set object_name = syn.name, object_schema = schema_name(syn.schema_id)
from sys.synonyms AS syn
where syn.object_id = #t1.object_id and object_type = @synonym

-- delete objects for which we could not resolve the table name or schema
-- because we may not have enough privileges
delete from #t1 
where 
    object_name is null or 
    (object_schema is null  and object_type not in (@assm, @part_func, @part_sch))

--final select
select object_id, object_type, relative_id, relative_type, object_name, object_schema, relative_name, relative_schema
 from #t1 
 order by rank, relative_id

drop table #t1
drop table #tempdep

IF @must_set_nocount_off > 0 
   set nocount off
```